# Issues in Merging local and remote files using WinMerge command in WinSCP

Tags: winscp, winmerge

I am using WinSCP and added Win-merge command

> "C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" /dr "!@:!/" "!^!" "!"

to merge both local and remote files easily. But, once i merged and saved the changes using this feature, for the first time it shows two files are identical. Later, when i try to open these two files again, it seems like the saved changes didn't affect the remote files. Can somebody suggest why i can't save my changes to remote files once i merge them?

Comment: *"for the first time it shows two files are identical"*: Do you mean that after you save the changes, close WinMerge, and start it again from WinSCP, they show as identical? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: What version of WinSCP are you using?

Comment: You should better ask a question like this on [su]. It's not really [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: "for the first time it shows two files are identical", I mean after i save the changes it says identical. But once i close winmerge and open it again i see the differences again. I am using WinSCP version 5.7.1.

Comment: I have no problems with your command. It works as expected. So you 1) Merge the changes from local file to the remote file 2) Close WinMerge 3) Get prompted to save the file [by the WinMerge], confirm? 3) Does WinSCP start upload? Do you get an overwrite confirmation prompt?

Comment: I tried as you explained. It asked confirmation to save. But it doesn't ask an overwrite confirmation prompt as you told in #3

Comment: Confirmation prompt for the remote file, right? Can you check a timestamp of the temporary copy of the remote file before and after save? What they are?

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade your winscp to latest versions preferably newer than 5.7 that will solve the problem for files i mean if you are comparing files and change anything in remote file it will take effect the problem you are facing is with older winscp versions however I am still having similar problem with folder compare i mean if i compare two folders and make any change in remote file next time the change is gone however it works perfectly if you are comparing files only